# website not running on locahost after exposing from dockerfile

Tags: docker, vue.js, nginx, dockerfile

I have created a multistaged dockerfile for running a vue.js based website but it is not running completely on localhost.

dockerfile:-

```
FROM node:16.9.1-alpine as dependencies
WORKDIR /app
RUN apk add --no-cache python3 make g++
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install


FROM node:16.9.1-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
COPY --from=dependencies /app/node_modules ./node_modules
RUN npm run build


FROM nginx:alpine
EXPOSE 80
COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

After running docker container this is the error I get -
`

```
172.17.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2023:17:36:55 +0000] "GET /ihr/img/icons/favicon-16x16.png HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "http://localhost:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
2023/04/21 17:36:56 [error] 30#30: *14 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/ihr/manifest.json" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /ihr/manifest.json HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/"
172.17.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2023:17:36:56 +0000] "GET /ihr/manifest.json HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "http://localhost:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
`
```

I tried to run on different ports on host system but it is not working still

Comment: What command are you using to run the container?